# Vector space theorem proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $V$ a vector space, $\mathbf{u}$ is a vector in $V$ and $c$ is a real scalar then

1) $c\mathbf{0}=\mathbf{0}$

2) $c\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$ $\rightarrow$ $c=0$ or $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$

How to show/prove this?

Note: I know I have to use the axioms of a vector space

Comment: I am stuck and don`t know how to approch it

Comment: The exact answer depends on what axioms you have to use. Some of them are equivalent to each other but may be presented in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
\begin{align*}
c\mathbf{0}&=c (\mathbf{0}+(-\mathbf{0})) & \text{def. of additive identity}\\
&= c\mathbf{0}+c (-\mathbf{0}) & \text{distributive property}\\
&= c \mathbf{0} - c \mathbf{0} & \text{$-\mathbf{u} = (-1) \mathbf{u}$ for any $\mathbf{u}$ (needs to be justified...)} \\
&= \mathbf{0} & \text{def. of additive identity}
\end{align*}

2)
I think you mean "$c \mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$ implies $c=0$ or $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$."

If $c=0$ we are done. Otherwise, $c\ne 0$. Multiplying both sides by $c^{-1}$ and applying part 1) shows that $\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: The fact that $c(\mathbf{v}-\mathbf{w})=c\mathbf{v}-c\mathbf{w}$ isn't part of the vector space axioms.

Answer (score 2):

Hints for you to understand and justify by the axioms of vector spaces:

1. - $\;c\cdot 0=c\cdot(0+0)=c\cdot0+c\cdot 0$
2. - $\;c\neq 0\implies 0=c\cdot u\implies c^{-1}\cdot 0=0=c^{-1}(c\cdot u)=(c^{-1}c)\cdot u=1\cdot u\;$